# How to get BUild Details in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am trying to get the build details progrmatically in VS 2010.

I want to get the latest build number and use this for printing on the Console.

I am struck at one point where I wanted 
 to get the details of the latest build that I have run and print it on the console.

```
 builddetailspec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
                IQueuedBuildQueryResult buildresult = buildserver.QueryQueuedBuilds(buildspec);
                if (buildresult.Failures.Length == 0 && buildresult.QueuedBuilds.Length > 0)
                {
                    IBuildDetail builddetail = buildresult.QueuedBuilds[0]
                      Console.WriteLine("Build Details :" + builddetail.BuildNumber);

                Console.ReadLine();

                }
```

At the IBuildDetail builddetail = buildresult.QueuedBuilds[0] , i am getting compile time error

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IQueuedBuild' to 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildDetail'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    c:\users\kepa\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\QueueBuild\QueueBuild\QueueBuild.cs 36  52  QueueBuild

I want to know , what could i prorbaly use to get the entire build details and then build number , Also is there an alternative way to get the build number.

Thanks,
Keerthi

Comment: I have solved this by using "buildresult.QueuedBuilds[0].Build"

Comment: I my Build Name is  : Core Script Automation 20160621.10  , I want this to be printed on my Console , but when I try to use Build Detail , I am unable to get this property of Build Detail.                                                                        Any Help is much appreciated on this

Comment: What do you get? The code is basically correct although I do not know about going after the queued builds in this scenario. BuildNumber is the correct member to get the final build name.  Flip out QueryQueuedBuilds with QueryBuild unless you really only want to query builds that are currently queued.

Comment: When I execute I get Build number :6902 ,but I wanted to print the build name on the console , I cannot find a property - buildname , which I can use to write on the console

Comment: Which build are you using, the old XAML or new Vnext?

Comment: Flip out QueryQueuedBuilds with QueryBuild unless you really only want to query builds that are currently queued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying from `QueryQueuedBuilds`, there is no build name in queryqueuebuids, only with the directly number such as 6902.

If you want to get ***Core Script Automation 20160621.10*,** you need to use [QueryBuilds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.querybuilds(v=vs.120).aspx)  directly.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have used QueryBuild instead of QueryQueuedBuild and it works the way I expected , thanks for the help